# Regular expression for matching letters followed by digits

Tags: python, regex

I have to match the citations within a document. The citations can be of the forms:
Author names, year; Author names(year); (Author names,year)
For example: 'James et al., 2010', 'James & Juda, 2010', 'James & Juda(2010)','(James & Juda, 2010)'.
I have tried:

```
[A-Za-z]+[0-9]{4}
```

and

```
(([A-Z]([A-Za-z][&.,])+\d{4})
```

One or more occurrences of characters followed by some punctuations and then 4 digits( specifying year) is what I meant. But its not working. Please help me with this regard.

Comment: `But its not working` ... can you show us the relevant code?

Comment: You are taking account of empty spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below regular expression will match all the samples which you have given.

`(\S+\s*)+?(,|\()\s*(\d+)\)?`

Comment: Hi, When I tried this on an entire string it doesn't work. The code is as follows:`s="James et al., (2010) proposes two algorithms namely Task severance and Task Parceling." s1= re.match(r'(\S+\s*)+?(,|\()\s*(\d+)\)?',s).string`. The output was the entire string. But what is required is only **James et al., (2010)**.

Comment: try `re.match(r'(\S+\s*)+?(,|\()\s*(\d+)\)?',s).group(0)`

Comment: Try regular expression at regex101.com  and it will give explanation of your regex.

Comment: Thanks. I will check it.